# Why does Django add "IS NULL" here?

Tags: django

Consider the following model:

```
class ProductCountry(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField('Product')
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    count = models.IntegerField()
```

And an expression `print(ProductCountry.objects.filter(product__product_id=request.GET.get('product').query)`.

Why does it give me the following?

```
SELECT "precomputed_product_country"."id", "precomputed_product_country"."product_id", "precomputed_product_country"."country_code", "precomputed_product_country"."count" FROM "precomputed_product_country" WHERE "precomputed_product_country"."product_id" IS NULL
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `product` key in `GET`?

Comment: @soon: you're right, this was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I didn't have a `product` key in GET, as user "soon" pointed out. Fixing the request solved the problem.